# Unable to Get Old values in Apex Trigger

Tags: apex

I am enhancing one logic where i need old value of a field when it is updated. I am using the below handler. Whts happening is i am able to get the old value of the field if i place the below piece of code in the constructor or in andFinally() method. Apart from these two places, if i place anywhere i am unable to get the old value. Anyone can explain whts wrong is happening..

Piece Of Code -

```
   for (SObject soo : Trigger.old) {
        Opportunity opp = (Opportunity)soo;
        S = opp.First_Digital_Product__c;
        system.debug('111111' + S);
    }
```

Handler -

```
public without sharing class OpportunityHandler implements ITrigger {




    /**
     * @description Constructor
     */
    public OpportunityHandler() { 

    if (Trigger.isUpdate){

        for (SObject soo : Trigger.old) {
            Opportunity opp = (Opportunity)soo;
            S = opp.First_Digital_Product__c;
            system.debug('111111' + S);
        }
        }
    }


    /**
     * @description This method is called prior to execution of a BEFORE 
     *              trigger. Use this to cache any data required into maps 
     *              prior execution of the trigger.
     */
    public void bulkBefore() { 



    }

    /**
     * @description This method is called iteratively for each record to be 
     *              inserted during a BEFORE trigger. Never execute any 
     *              SOQL/SOSL etc in this and other iterative methods.
     * @param SObject The record of the current iteration.
     */
    public void beforeInsert(SObject so) {



    }

    /**
     * @description This method is called iteratively for each record to be 
     *              updated during a BEFORE trigger. Never execute any 
     *              SOQL/SOSL etc in this and other iterative methods.
     * @param SObject The old record of the current iteration.
     * @param SObject The new record of the current iteration.
     */
    public void beforeUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so) { 



    }

    /**
     * @description This method is called iteratively for each record to be 
     *              deleted during a BEFORE trigger. Never execute any 
     *              SOQL/SOSL etc in this and other iterative methods.
     * @param SObject The record of the current iteration.
     */
    public void beforeDelete(SObject so) {


     }

    /**
     * @description This method is called iteratively for each record inserted 
     *              during an AFTER trigger. Always put field validation in the
     *              'After' methods in case another trigger has modified any 
     *              values. The record is 'read only' by this point. Never 
     *              execute any SOQL/SOSL etc in this and other iterative 
     *              methods.
     * @param SObject The record of the current iteration.
     */
    public void afterInsert(SObject so) { 


    }

    /**
     * @description This method is called iteratively for each record updated 
     *              during an AFTER trigger. Never execute any SOQL/SOSL etc 
     *              in this and other iterative methods.
     * @param SObject The old record of the current iteration.
     * @param SObject The new record of the current iteration.
     */
    public void afterUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so) { 


        // End YBS 4/15/2013
    }

    /**
     * @description This method is called iteratively for each record deleted 
     *              during an AFTER trigger. Never execute any SOQL/SOSL etc 
     *              in this and other iterative methods.
     * @param SObject The record of the current iteration.
     */
    public void afterDelete(SObject so) { 



    }

    //Sajana Thomas - 13 Oct 2014 - Added method to calculate # of Opportunities 
    /**
     * @description This method is called to calculate the Number of Opportunities 
                    on a deal object
     * @param Id the deal id of the current opportunity.
     * @param String the action that needs to be taken - Add or Sub.
     */
    public void updateDealMap(Id dealId, String sAction) {


    }

    /**
     * @description This method is called iteratively for each record undeleted 
     *              during an AFTER trigger. Never execute any SOQL/SOSL etc 
     *              in this and other iterative methods.
     * @param SObject The record of the current iteration.
     */
    public void afterUndelete(SObject so) { 



    }

    /**
     * @description This method is called to calculate the anticipated 
     *              date if issue date is not available
     * @param Opportunity The current Opportunity record
     */
    public static Date calculateAnticipatedDate(Opportunity oOpportunity) {

    }


    /**
     * @description This method is called once all records have been processed
     *              by the trigger. Use this method to accomplish any final 
     *              operations such as creation or updates of other records.
     */
    public void andFinally() { 



    } // End of AndFinally()

    // This method will make sure that all of the Opportunities have Sales Assignments
    // for the Products that are assigned to the Opportunity.
    private void checkOpportunitySalesAssignments(List<Opportunity> opportunities) {



}
```

Regards

Comment: You would have to show us how ITrigger is implemented and how it is called from the actual trigger.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see you are using the [the Apex Tidy Trigger pattern](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers)

Assuming you faithfully copy-pasted the `TriggerFactory` class from the pattern, then your handler should look like this:

```
 public without sharing class OpportunityTriggerHandler implements ITrigger {

   public OpportunityTriggerHandler() {} // nothing goes in here
   }

   // bulkbefore and bulkafter handlers to fetch related objects

   public void beforeUpdate(SObject oldSobj, SObject sobj) {
     Opportunity o            = (Opportunity) sobj;
     Opportunity oOld          = (Opportunity) oldSobj;
     // do something useful, e.g. comparing oOld to oNew, addError, etc.
   }
   public void afterUpdate(SObject oldSobj, SObject sobj) {
     Opportunity o            = (Opportunity) sobj;
     Opportunity oOld          = (Opportunity) oldSobj;
     // do something useful as required in after context
   }
   //  other handlers as per the pattern

   // andFinally handler to insert/update related records
}
```